# Android pre-L, appcompat-v7:24.2.1 and background theme reference crash

Tags: android, android-layout

I have just inherited old code, which more or less does something like this:

(names are changed)

```
   <attr name="my_reference" format="reference"/>

   <style name="my_style_a" parent="@style/AppTheme">
   <item name="my_reference">@drawable/drawable_a</item>
   </style>

   <style name="my_style_b" parent="@style/AppTheme">
   <item name="my_reference">@drawable/drawable_b</item>
   </style>
```

drawable_a and drawable_b:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

And then there is a piece of layout:

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?my_reference"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

The trick is that style is loaded programmatically (it must change as user clicks a button):

```
  ContextThemeWrapper contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeId);
  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contextThemeWrapper);

  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, parent, false);
```

Inflating that last view throws exception on android 4.4 and below (it works fine on 5.0+)

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010010 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1967)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3337)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
```

And it happened only after I had updated com.android.support:appcompat-v7 library to 24+ (since I need new API). It works fine on appcompat-v7, version 18 (or something like this), but it's not an option to remain with old library (neither can I drop support for pre-L android versions...)

Is there any simple fix for this (not including rewriting half of app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so after some digging, I've found a solution:

you just need to set a theme before view is inflated:

```
activity.setTheme(themeId);
```